# How to resolve postcss-loader error regarding comment-out

Tags: vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js, storybook

### summery

I've tried to run Storybook in Nuxt.js project.
But it ends with following errors:

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@storybook/vue/node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
SyntaxError

(1:1) Unknown word

> 1 | // Imports
    | ^
  2 | var ___CSS_LOADER_API_IMPORT___ = require("../../node_modules/css-loader/dist/runtime/api.js");
  3 | exports = ___CSS_LOADER_API_IMPORT___(false);
Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@storybook/vue/node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
SyntaxError

(1:1) Unknown word

> 1 | // Imports
    | ^
  2 | var ___CSS_LOADER_API_IMPORT___ = require("../../node_modules/css-loader/dist/runtime/api.js");
  3 | exports = ___CSS_LOADER_API_IMPORT___(false);

    at Object../node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/@storybook/vue/node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js?!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./components/list_test/index.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=4656082a&scoped=true&lang=css& (http://localhost:6006/main.4b5cc2aaa31bfcea8926.bundle.js:565:7)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:6006/runtime~main.4b5cc2aaa31bfcea8926.bundle.js:849:30)
    at fn (http://localhost:6006/runtime~main.4b5cc2aaa31bfcea8926.bundle.js:151:20)
    at Object../node_modules/style-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/@storybook/vue/node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js?!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./components/list_test/index.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=4656082a&scoped=true&lang=css& (http://localhost:6006/main.4b5cc2aaa31bfcea8926.bundle.js:577:27)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:6006/runtime~main.4b5cc2aaa31bfcea8926.bundle.js:849:30)
    at fn (http://localhost:6006/runtime~main.4b5cc2aaa31bfcea8926.bundle.js:151:20)
    at Module../components/list_test/index.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=4656082a&scoped=true&lang=css& (http://localhost:6006/main.4b5cc2aaa31bfcea8926.bundle.js:478:467)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:6006/runtime~main.4b5cc2aaa31bfcea8926.bundle.js:849:30)
    at fn (http://localhost:6006/runtime~main.4b5cc2aaa31bfcea8926.bundle.js:151:20)
    at Module../components/list_test/index.vue (http://localhost:6006/main.4b5cc2aaa31bfcea8926.bundle.js:409:165)
```

I want to know how to resolve this error and runs Storybook without errors.

### show some code

I put following setttings in `./storybook/webpack.config.js` because of `scss` usage.

```
  config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.s?css$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loaders: [
      'style-loader',
      'css-loader',
      'sass-loader'
  ]});
```

Environment is `Ubuntu20.04`.